# Docker Backend Deployment Can Not Find Path '/app/package.json' - DigitalOcean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, deployment, digital-ocean

I am running into an issue where my deployment logs are showing an error where it can't find the package.json. I believe this has to do something with the volumes I defined but I can seem to debug this.

Dockerfile For Backend

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13

RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app

RUN mkdir /app && chown app:app /app

USER app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker Compose

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: unless-stopped
  api:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    environment:
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://localhost:27017/paradise
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
  db:
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - paradise:/data/db
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  paradise:
```

Docker Deployment Logs

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: This question is a little difficult to answer without knowing your directory structure and the context of the docker file for your backend. It appears your COPY command for your package*.json files failed. Is your Dockerfile for your backend at the same directory level as your package.json?

Comment: @KevinCodes Hi Kevin, yes it is on the same level as the package.json.

Comment: Okay. next question, is your backend directory holding the docker file and the package.json for your backend?

Where is the docker compose file in relation to your ./backend and your ./frontend directories?

Comment: Directory structure matters a bit especially with Compose. I would recommend trying to add `context: <relative path from compose to your backend dockerfile>` to your `api` section of your Docker Compose file (much like you have it for the `web` section).

Comment: @KevinCodes Theres a frontend folder (React), backend folder (express) and then a docker-compose outside of that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you trying to execute a build in a directory ./backend where you actually marked it as ./app

Comment: Hmm, how would you suggest I fix this by chance?

Comment: Ive also spotted you have COPY package*.json ./ try changing that to  COPY package.json . Without the start and forward dash. Your volumes might be right unless it still has issues with the  ./backend or  ./frontend part on docker side afterwards, however lets first get it to build.